# ConnectionString lost on second execute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core 2.0 and dapper. I have a class that wraps an IDbConnection Interface and only exposes certain methods. Here is a short version of that class.

```
public class MyConnectionString : IMyConnectionString
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public int ConnectionTimeout => _connection.ConnectionTimeout;
    public string Database => _connection.Database;
    public string ConnectionString { get => null; set => _connection.ConnectionString = value; }
    public ConnectionState State => _connection.State;

    public MyConnectionString(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper)
    {
        var con = "some logic to get the connection string.";
        _connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    }

    public int Execute(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        using (var con = _connection) { return con.Execute(query, parameters); }
    }
}
```

I am injecting this class via a constructor to my Repository services. For example, this is a method that would call it:

```
internal class SomeRepository
{
    private readonly IMyConnectionString _connection;

    public SomeRepository(IMyConnectionString connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public void ExecuteSomeQuery(Object params)
    {
        var query = "Some query...";
        _connection.Execute(query, params);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that if I call `_connection.Execute(query, params);` twice in a single request (2 different services), the second time it gets called the `ConnectionString` value inside `MyConnectionString` class is empty. I have tried binding it in Transient and Request scope to see if it would preserve it, but no luck. Any idea on why this is happening or how can I preserve it so that I won't have to create the connection string every time it is requested?

Comment: "ConnectionString value inside MyConnectionString class is empty"... `ConnectionString { get => return null; ...`, how do you expect it to return anything but `null`?

Comment: Also `using (var con = _connection)` effectively disposes the `_connection` after the first execution.

Comment: You should instead create a new connection on every request. There'll be hardly any overhead, due to connection pooling. Also, what is the purpose of using a Facade to only expose certain of Dappers methods? I don't see any gain in this.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Not all `IDbConnection` objects are cheap - connection-pooling only applies to SQL Server and possibly other third-party connections. Connections to Access/JET databases are expensive and should be long-lived, for example.

Comment: @Dai Certainly, but based on his question I would safely assume he's using Sql Server, since he's creating `SqlConnection` objects.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't think you understood the code. it is not supposed to return the connection outside of the object.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Thanks for the input, there are design reasons behind this that I would rather not get into as it is off topic. But bottom line, there actually is a benefit to what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrapping the `Connection` inside a `using` disposes the `Connection` at his end of execution: just as @Jasen said in comments.

I would, in your case, just get the connection and execute on the `Connection` created in the constructor: removing the `using` completely.

You should not create the `SqlConnection`, since you are implementing dependency injection. You should:

- Implement `IDisposable` to dispose your connection when your class is collected.
- Pass a `SqlConnection` factory to create your `SqlConnection`, seperating your creation logic from your class.

Your class should resemble something like this:

```
public class MyConnectionString : IMyConnectionString
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public int ConnectionTimeout => _connection.ConnectionTimeout;
    public string Database => _connection.Database;
    public string ConnectionString 
    {     
        get => null; 
        set => _connection.ConnectionString = value; 
    }

    public ConnectionState State => _connection.State;

    public MyConnectionString(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper)
    {
        string con = "some logic to get the connection string.";
        _connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    }

    public int Execute(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        return _connection.Execute(query, parameters);
    }
}
```

With `IDisposable` implementation:

```
using System;
public class MyConnectionString : IMyConnectionString, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public int ConnectionTimeout => _connection.ConnectionTimeout;
    public string Database => _connection.Database;
    public string ConnectionString 
    {     
        get => null; 
        set => _connection.ConnectionString = value; 
    }

    public ConnectionState State => _connection.State;

    public MyConnectionString(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper)
    {
        string con = "some logic to get the connection string.";
        _connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    }

    public int Execute(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        return _connection.Execute(query, parameters);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

With your own `ISqlConnectionFactory` factory:

```
public class MyConnectionString : IMyConnectionString, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
    private readonly ISqlConnectionFactory _factory;

    public int ConnectionTimeout => _connection.ConnectionTimeout;
    public string Database => _connection.Database;
    public string ConnectionString 
    {     
        get => null; 
        set => _connection.ConnectionString = value; 
    }

    public ConnectionState State => _connection.State;

    public MyConnectionString(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper, ISqlConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _connection = _factory.CreateConnection(connProvOpts, encHelper);
    }

    public int Execute(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        return _connection.Execute(query, parameters);
    }
}

public interface ISqlConnectionFactory
{
    SqlConnection CreateConnection(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper);
}

public class SqlConnectionFactory : ISqlConnectionFactory
{
    public SqlConnectionFactory()
    {
         // Maybe initialization?
    }

    public SqlConnection CreateConnection(IOptions<ConnectionProviderOptions> connProvOpts, EncryptionHelper encHelper)
    {
        string con = "some logic to get the connection string.";
        _connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    }
}
```

Personally, I would have created and disposed the `Connection` each time `Execute` is invoked. This means that outside of `Execute`, your connection is closed and resources are released.

Comment: If you do this, you should either inject the `SqlConnection` or implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: True, I was wondering where his connection string was coming from. Surely from his constructor parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought that because I am creating a new variable, that the object gets duplicated and the new object gets disposed, not the original.

Comment: I have a sub-question. I have some logic that reads the connection string from appsettings.json and then it decrypts it. This means that every time I open a connection, I have to do this step all over again. Does this feels too much processing? Does it has to be this way, is there a better way?

Comment: @Bojan Connections should live as little as possible. You could store the decrypted value in-memory and discard the connection

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've been taught that storing the connection string in a variable is bad practice. One of the reasons why I have the `ConnectionString { get => null;}` is to prevent any class from reading it.

Comment: It's bad to store the constant value, not a decrypted/processed/built one, as a `private static` field. If I wanted, I could read it from the `_connection` field anyway

Comment: @Bojan: You should keep your connection as short-lived as possible, even if it is creating your connection everytime you want to connect to the database. The fact that you were taught that is that your `appsetting.json` file may change during the life of your class. This means that you don't get the latest value of your settings.

Comment: Keeping the connection alive in the `MyConnectionString` class may have unfortunate consequences depending how it is registered with the IoC container. I definitely agree that you should dispose the connection immediately after using it, if for nothing else than to free up the connection in the pool.

Comment: I do agree that it needs to be disposed of right away. I am just contemplating the extra processing I would do for each query just to get that connection versus storing the decrypted value somewhere. Maybe SecureString is way to go? Loop through it each time after to get the value, would be less processing than reading from file and decrypting each time.

Comment: You could add a cache validation unto your decrypted connectionstring. You read/decrypt the connection string and keep it inside your class with a `DateTime _lastReadConnectionString`. Whenever a certain delay is hit, you refresh and read/decrypt the connection string. You can also force the refresh by invoking the class to refresh his connection string whenever you like.

Comment: Configure your connection string on application startup and store it in a private readonly variable passed in the constructor for the SqlConnectionFactory that Etienne suggested above. If you're concerned that your connection string is exposed in memory after encryption, you have different issues to worry about. You may have misunderstood that bad practice you mention about storing the connection string in a variable.

Comment: From my understanding is the possibility of memory dumps exposing the string is what the big fear is.

Comment: I would recommend at this moment creating a new question about the memory dumps and connection strings. I'm sure someone actually thought about a solution for this matter.